# Query on indexed table in sql database versus using own HashMap

Tags: java, sql, database, performance, h2

I have a performance question in java.

I have a large indexed table in a sql database (in this case a H2 Database, but the question can be applied to any sql database).

I have to find items in this table by this index often.

Now I wonder what is quicker:

- the query on the sql database
- making your own hashmap for the fields I use most freqently

Does anyone have an idea about this? (before creating some speed tests and find out for myselve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking up in the HashMap will be quicker, but if the data changes you have the overhead of managing the data and updating your cache, not to mention deciding on which bits of data you are going to cache.

Note that your database will probably do some caching of its own and common queries will probably return data very quickly without even going through the query parser, never mind hitting the disk.

Comment: In this case the data doesn't change. However, the option of caching is interesting to figure out whether H2 Database uses this.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve an indexed SQL query in 1-10 milli-seconds, and a lookup on a HashMap should be less than 1 micro-second.

If you have an SQL database already, I would just use that unless you *know* you have to replicate the data in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Using Your own HashMap to maintain will make you life tough
   What if you have too many entries to accommodate in memory
   What if your application is re-started?
   What if you need search on one more parameter you didn't think of?
   What if you need to search like param1=val1 and param2=val2

DB provides these things out of the box if you maintain right set of indexes.
And most modern DB keeps frequently queried data in its cache so thing should be faster.